# JavaScript: Read an item AWS dynamodb

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to read the data on my table_user in dynamodb: 
[My database [Please look]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EQSa.png)

```
 AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/',
  // accessKeyId default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB. 
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  accessKeyId: "fake",
  // secretAccessKey default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB. 
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  secretAccessKey: "fake"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function queryData() {
    document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Querying for movies from 1985.";

   var table = "table_users";


var title = "love";

var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "rawa_rese": title
    }
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
}
```

But getting:

> Unable to read item. Error JSON: { "message": "Requested resource not
>   found", "code": "ResourceNotFoundException", "time":
>   "2018-12-27T17:17:56.207Z", "requestId":
>   "G06LO9DH60AB9OK419826ISNJNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG", "statusCode":
>   400, "retryable": false, "retryDelay": 0, "line": 36, "column": 29583,
>   "sourceURL": "https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js" }

How do i get this record `love`?

Comment: That error ususally indicates that the table doesn't exist. Confirm that the table `table_users` exists in us-west-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo. You have used `table_users` where the table name is `table_user`